# How to get all characters upto a number?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have strings like below

```
>>> s1
'this_is-a.string-123-with.number'
>>> s2
'this_is-a123.456string-123-with.number'
>>> s3
'one-0more-str.999'
```

need to get everything before all-numbers (not alphanumeric) after splitting, so get `this_is-a.string-` from `s1` and `this_is-a123.456string-` from s2 and `one-0more-str.` from s3.

```
>>> for a in re.split('-|_|\.',s2):
...    if a.isdigit():
...       r=re.split(a,s2)[0]
...       break
>>> print(r)
# expected: this_is-a123.456string-
# got: this_is-a
```

Above piece of code works for s1, but not for s2, as `123` matches `a123` in s2, there should be a better pythonic way?

More info:

with `s3` example, when we split with `-` or `_` or `.` as delimiter, 999 is the only thing we get as all numbers, so everything before that is `one-0more-str.` which needs to be printed, if we take `s2` as example, after splitting with dash or underbar or dot as delimiter, `123` will be the `all number` (isdigit), so get everything before that which is `this_is-a123.456string-`, so if input string is going to be `this_1s-a-4.test`, output should be `this_1s-a-`, because 4 is the all-number after splitting.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, `this_is-a.string-` from s1 and `this_is-a123.456string-` from s2

Comment: How should a piece of code know which numbers from the original string should be included in the returned string?

Comment: You say you need to get everything before "all numbers" however your expect output for s2 includes numbers. Can you clarify?

Comment: after splitting, if its all numbers, then I need everything before that, so in s2, I need to get everything before `123`, because `123` is `all numbers` (ignoring a123 and 456string) after splitting.

Comment: @ChrisCharley, thanks, but its not `-` used around the number always, please see the `s3` example.

Comment: what do you mean by `all numbers`? why is `['this_is-a', '.', 'string-', '-with.number']` not an acceptable answer for `s2`?

Comment: Then this will match all 3 strings w/o the end number `m = re.match(r'(.+[-.])\d', s3).group(1)`

Comment: I see you've added another sample input: `'one-0more-str.999'` Why should a piece of code return:`'one-0more-str.'` ? I don't understand your rules.

Comment: @quamrana because when you split with `- or _ or .` as delimiter, `999` is the only thing you get as `all numbers`, so everything before that is `one-0more-str.`, if you take `s2` as example, after splitting with dash or underbar or dot as delimiter, `123` will be the all number (isdigit), so get everything before that which is `this_is-a123.456string-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for your example cases:

```python
def fn(s):
    return re.match("(.*?[-_.]|^)\d+([-_.]|$)", s).group(1)
```

(`^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string respectively and the `?` in `.*?` does a non-greedy match.)

Some more cases:

```
>>> fn("111")
""

>>> fn(".111")
"."

>>> fn(".1.11")
"."
```

You might also want to think about what you want to get if there is no group of all numbers:

```
>>> fn("foobar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will work in all cases but you can try:

```
for a in re.split('-|_|\.',s2).reverse():
    if a.isdigit():
        r=re.rsplit(a,s2)[0]
        break
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for you examples

**Code**

```
def parse(s):
  """ Splits on successive digits, 
      then takes everything up to last split on digits """
  return ''.join(re.split(r'(\d+)', s)[:-2])
```

**Tests**

Using specified strings

```
for t in ['this_is-a.string-123-with.number',
          'this_is-a123.456string-123-with.number',
          'one-0more-str.999']:
    print(f'{parse(t)}')
```

**Output**

```
this_is-a.string-
this_is-a123.456string-
one-0more-str.
```

**Explanation**

String

```
s = 'this_is-a123.456string-123-with.number'
```

Split on group of digits

```
re.split(r'(\d+)', s)
Out: ['this_is-a', '123', '.', '456', 'string-', '123', '-with.number']
```

Leave out last two items in split

```
re.split(r'(\d+)', s)[:-2] # [:-2] slice dropping last two items of list
Out: ['this_is-a', '123', '.', '456', 'string-']
```

Join list into string

```
''.join(re.split(r'(\d+)', s)[:-2]) # join items
Out: this_is-a123.456string-
```

Comment: Thanks, whyc is `[:-2]` needed?

Comment: @rodee--added an explanation which hopefully clarifies this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want, you can use a single regular expression to get the values you need:

```python
import re
s1='this_is-a.string-123-with.number'
s2='this_is-a123.456string-123-with.number'
s3='one-0more-str.999'

# matches any group that is in between "all numbers"...
regex = re.compile('(.*[-\._])\d+([-\._].*)?')  

m = regex.match(s1)
print(m.groups())

m = regex.match(s2)
print(m.groups())

m = regex.match(s3)
print(m.groups())
```

when you run this the result is the following:

```
('this_is-a.string-', '-with.number')
('this_is-a123.456string-', '-with.number')
('one-0more-str.', None)
```

If you are interested only in the first group you can use only:

```python
>>> print(m.group(1))
one-0more-str.
```

If you want to filter for the cases where there is no second group:

```python
>>> print([i for i in m.groups() if i])
['one-0more-str.']
```